# Are code-only answers a good thing?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, code

I just stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16073387/156755). While the question itself is not perfect, both the answers to date have just been blocks of code.

When I reply to a question, I usually (admittedly, not always) add a sentence or two explaining what the OP was doing wrong.

Are code-only answers a good thing? Or should we try to educate as well as solve the issue?

Comment: One of the answers just now had text edited in.

Comment: I will always upvote the answers that actually explain the code and why it solves their problem over the ones that just provide the code.

Comment: @DavidRobinson That _may_ be a result of my comment?